# SML check if 2 items are in the same list

Tags: sml, member, smlnj

How do i check if 2 items are in the same list in sml? I tried changing a member function but i could not make it work.

```
val routeList1 = ["Princes Street", "Haymarket", "Craiglockhart", "Musselburgh", "Stoneybank"]
```

if want to check if both `"Princes Street"` and `"Haymarket"` are in `routeList1`

I am new to this language, so any help would be nice

Comment: If you know how to check if one thing is in a list why is it hard to check if two things are? Just use the `andalso` Boolean operator.

Answer (score 1):

To check if `"Princes Street"` is in `routeList1`, you could write:

```
List.exists (fn s => s = "Princes Street") routeList1
```

(which uses `List.exists` *[[see doc](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.exists:VAL)]* to check for an element `s` such that `s = "Princes Street"` is `true`).

To check for two strings, just check for one, then the other:

```
List.exists (fn s => s = "Princes Street") routeList1
  andalso List.exists (fn s => s = "Haymarket") routeList1
```

Answer (score 1):

You might call a function that checks for membership

```
fun elem x ys = List.exists (fn y => x = y) ys
```

And a function that checks for membership of many things

```
fun allElems xs ys = List.all (fn x => elem x ys) xs
```

assuming that elements can only be compared for equality. Then

```
val areThey = allElems ["Princes Street", "Haymarket"] routeList1
```